# How to bind multiple data frames (.csv files ) into one data frame

Tags: r

I have a bunch of df saves as 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, 4.csv, 5.csv, ... 10.csv)
Whats an efficient way to bind say for example the first 5 into one df such as one_five <- (include  1-5.csv)

I want to know another way than rbind as I got about 400 different dfs.

Thanks

Comment: `do.call(rbind,lapply(list.files(pattern='.csv'),function(x) read.csv(x)))`

Comment: No anonymous function needed! `do.call(rbind,lapply(list.files(pattern='.csv'), read.csv))`

Comment: This will bind all the df into one. I got 400 df and I want a multiple of 20 into one df, making 20 different df. I will need a way where I can specify for example from 1-20.csv into one df and so on.